# Creating new column with arithmetic only if first column has same ID using awk

Tags: unix, awk, calculated-columns

If I have a file which is in the form:

```
ID Temp   Time
0  1      0.1
0  2      0.2
0  1      0.3
0  2      0.4
1  1      0.1
1  2      0.2
1  2      0.4
1  3      0.6
```

I want to add a third column which uses the difference in Value2 in adjacent rows, and multiplies it by Value 1 for rows with same ID, so the expected output would be:

```
ID Temp   Time   Calculated
0  1      0.1    
0  2      0.2    0.1
0  1      0.3    0.2
0  2      0.4    0.1
1  1      0.1    
1  2      0.2    0.1
1  2      0.4    0.4
1  3      0.6    0.4
```

Which I can almost get using the code:

```
awk 'NR>1{$4=(($3-p)*(q))} {p=$3} {q=$2} 1' input> output
```

But this runs over the change of ID giving:

```
ID Temp   Time   Calculated
0  1      0.1    
0  2      0.2    0.1
0  1      0.3    0.2
0  2      0.4    0.1
1  1      0.1    -0.6
1  2      0.2    0.1
1  2      0.4    0.4
1  3      0.6    0.4
```

Except this should restart everytime the ID changes and not carry on, is there a way to add this to awk?

Comment: what would be the ```Value 1 for rows with same ID``` for your sample input?
The description is a bit ambiguous...

Comment: @vgersh99 The Different ID numbers are different locations, Value1 is the Temperature and Value2 is the Time the measurement was taken - So Value1 could be any positive number.

Comment: this is still unclear. Again, what should the "multiplier" be for your sample input file?

Comment: @vgersh99 Sorry I did a terrible job of formatting this originally and had to update the tables so this might be clearer now, but I dont understand what you mean. The new entry is the Difference between The current time value and the one before, multiplied by the Temperature from the time before. So to get the first calculated value of 0.1, we do (0.2-0.1)*(1)=0.1

Comment: @user15006570: Can you explain why new value in last row is `0.4` instead of `0.6`?

Comment: @anubhava (0.6-0.4)*(2)=0.4 or (Current Time - Previous Time)*(Previous Temp). The formula for calculation works fine, the problem is it needs to restart once the ID changes as we are now at a new point, or maybe loop over the ID's somehow? I'm new to unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR == 1 {print $0, "Calculated"; next} {print $0, (NR>2 && p1 == $1 ? ($3-p3)*p2 : "")} {p1 = $1; p2 = $2; p3 = $3}' file

ID Temp   Time  Calculated
0  1      0.1
0  2      0.2   0.1
0  1      0.3   0.2
0  2      0.4   0.1
1  1      0.1
1  2      0.2   0.1
1  2      0.4   0.4
1  3      0.6   0.4
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR == 1 {
   print $0, "Calculated"
   next
}
{
   print $0, (NR > 2 && p1 == $1 ? ($3 - p3) * p2 : "")
}
{
   p1 = $1
   p2 = $2
   p3 = $3
}' file
```